# Switch focus to a different tab in a pivot control in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-controls

Is it possible to switch focus between tabs with code in a Pivot control in a c# uwp app?
I tried using `Pivot.SelectedIndex = 1;` but that does not do the trick.
Is it not possible or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: This was never an "XP look" but a Common Controls 6.x uxTheme.  In any case, this problem seems to occur with either the whole-cloth-private MSCOMCTL.OCX or the CC6-wrapping COMCTL32.OCX ToolBar controls.  I doubt there is a way around it that doesn't involve a 3rd party OCX, though I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked.  This has not been an issue for me though I have seen other struggle with it before and never found an answer myself working with the Microsoft OCX.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so so you have my apologies,
I know you probably wont want to do this but if you want you could make your own controls so that way they don't have the background like a toolbar and even if it does have a background you could change the background color, hope this helps.

Comment: I found some sample program that allows that http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=44348&d=1137107059 but still, there must be a different way to accomplish this, sometimes it seems so complicated and when you see how simple it actually is you think why didn't I think of that?